# What kind of WWII aircaft is this?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I saw this plane at a warbird fly in and would appreciate some assistance identifying it.

I can only tell you what I'm rather sure it's *not*..

<s>Grumman TBF Avenger</s>

<s>Other US-operated Torpedo Bomber types</s>

<s>Grumman F4F-3 Wildcat</s>

<s>Republic P-47 Thunderbolt</s>

Any ideas?

[image]

[EDIT]

Also, is this yellow aircraft the same model, only with a different paint scheme? The nose looks different, but perhaps the cap/cone has been removed, perhaps for maintenance. Otherwise the canopy, wheels, and gear covers look identical.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [North American T-6 Texan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-6_Texan) Trainer, probably the NJ/SNJ Texan variant.

[image: SNJ 1]

"[SNJ-1 at NAS Pensacola c1940](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SNJ-1_at_NAS_Pensacola_c1940.jpeg#/media/File:SNJ-1_at_NAS_Pensacola_c1940.jpeg)" by U.S. Navy - U.S. Navy National Museum of Naval Aviation photo No. 1996.488.166.090. Licensed under Public Domain via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

The North American Aviation T-6 Texan is a single-engined advanced trainer aircraft used to train pilots of various air forces including (but not limited to) USAAF, USN, RAF from (before) WWII well into the 1970s.

Comment: Thanks, @aeroalias. Please see my edit--is the yellow aircraft I added also a T-6 Texan? It looks very similar and I nearly created a separate question for it, but after reading your wiki link (noting they are common at air shows), I'm wondering if it is indeed the same model aircraft.

Comment: @elrobis http://www.aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=66332

Comment: Ahh gotcha: "Markings Applied: TA-533, 12533, 77". Thanks CG!

Comment: Note that without verifying the serial number we can't know _for sure_ but I'd hazard that the airplane in the link I gave you and your photo #2 are one and the same bird.

Comment: Where did you spot these? Do. They appear to be based there?